# cv2.imshow() displaying blank, unresponsive window

Tags: macos, python-2.7, opencv

My cv2.imshow() function doesn't work. All it displays is the window bar and nothing else.

[image: Unresponsive window]

And here's my code (As you can see, I've added cv2.waitkey()):

[image: Code]

Comment: Known bug, see the duplicate question.

Comment: BTW, it's preferred to show your code as text (there's special markup for that), rather than as images -- it's a lot easier to paste that into an editor when someone wants to try it ;) | And even though this is a duplicate, I'll give you a +1 for that `waitKey` bit ;)

Comment: If you installed OpenCV through the `pip` package `opencv-python`, then the GUI components won't work---did you compile from source? If so then the duplicate stands. @DanMašek is this bug reported on GitHub?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds This AFAICT: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8885 | This OSX issue with only the title bar of the window showing has been appearing here quite frequently lately. | If compiled without GUI support, you wouldn't even see that title bar.

Comment: @DanMašek I followed the instructions and it worked for me. Thank you so much!!